# Notificações de desktop no Chrome com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Tenho uma aplicação na qual preciso enviar notificações para o usuário, e gostaria que estas aparecessem no desktop, conforme o exemplo abaixo. É possível fazê-lo com `JavaScript`? Se sim, como? Não queria utilizar o `alert()`, pois o acho inconveniente. Não precisa funcionar em outros navegadores.

**Exemplo de noficicação do "Checker Plus"**

[image: exemplo]

Comment: Você provavelmente vai receber diversas respostas com sugestões de implementação. Ainda assim, dá uma olhada nesse plugin pra jQuery beeeemmmm bacana: http://notifyjs.com/

Comment: @LuizVieira, não encontrei a parte de notificações para desktop nesse plugin.

Comment: Da uma olhada aqui: https://github.com/irclife/ichat.io/blob/master/assets/javascripts/ichat.io.js#L20:L50 Praticamente eu criei um method generico dentro desse projeto onde ele identifica o Browser e gera a notificação!

Comment: Ah, essa não faz notificação no desktop, foi mals. Na verdade a que faz no Desktop é essa aqui: https://github.com/alexgibson/notify.js (que é construida sobre a API Notification da resposta do @mgibsonbr).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Há uma funcionalidade sendo planejada para o HTML5 chamada [`Notification`](http://notifications.spec.whatwg.org/) (no momento [somente suportada](http://caniuse.com/#feat=notifications) [no desktop] pelos Firefox, Chrome e Safari):

```javascript
Notification.requestPermission(/* opcional: callback */);

...

var notification = new Notification("Título", {
    icon: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmHl0.png',
    body: "Texto da notificação"
});
notification.onclick = function() {
    window.open("http://stackoverflow.com");
}
```

[Exemplo no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/TPJBn/1/).

---

### Solução específica para o WebKit

Você pode fazê-lo através de `window.webkitNotifications`, conforme o exemplo abaixo:

```js
var havePermission = window.webkitNotifications.checkPermission();
if (havePermission == 0) {
  // 0 is PERMISSION_ALLOWED
  var notification = window.webkitNotifications.createNotification(
    'https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmHl0.png',
    'Chrome notification!',
    'Here is the notification text'
  );

  notification.onclick = function () {
    window.open("https://stackoverflow.com/a/13328397/1269037");
    notification.close();
  }
  notification.show();
} else {
    window.webkitNotifications.requestPermission();
}
```

[Exemplo no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/TPJBn/). Ao clicar pela primeira vez, o browser pedirá permissão ao usuário para exibir notificações. Após aceita, futuros cliques vão exibir a notificação.

Nota: de acordo com a [API](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/desktop-notifications/api-specification) do chromium (base do Google Chrome, para quem não sabe), o método `requestPermission` **precisa** ser chamado em resposta a uma ação do usuário, caso contrário não terá efeito.

> This method should only be called while handling a user gesture; in other circumstances it will have no effect.

Entretanto, uma vez que a permissão foi concedida, você poderá chamar `createNotification` quando quiser (talvez em resposta a um *polling* no servidor, ou a uma mensagem de um `WebSocket`, etc). O `requestPermission` também aceita um *callback*, se você quiser ser notificado quando o usuário aceitar/recusar a permissão.

Há também uma funcionalidade chamada [rich notifications](http://blog.chromium.org/2013/05/rich-notifications-in-chrome.html) - que extende bastante os tipos de conteúdos suportados na notificação - mas não a conheço em detalhes. [Link para a API](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/notifications.html).

Fonte do código de exemplo: [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13328513/520779) no SOEN

Comment: Muito interessante isto! À suporte para este tipo de cenários em outros navegadores? _Off-topic_, mas fiquei curioso :)

Comment: @Zuul Há [um padrão sendo plenejado](http://notifications.spec.whatwg.org/), mas no momento [apenas o Chrome e o Firefox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=notifications) já dão suporte a ele.

Comment: @Zuul atualizei a resposta com um exemplo usando esse novo padrão.

Comment: Muito bom, vou brincar um pouco com isso no final de semana! _(é nestes momentos que o sistema deveria permitir mais que um UpVote)_

Comment: Excelente resposta.