# Como dar o foco em um pop-up de 1 em 1 minuto?

Tags: javascript

Como dar o foco em um pop-up de 1 em 1 minuto? Lembrando que o pop-up está minimizado e eu quero deixar ele "em evidência" na tela do usuário.

Comment: até aonde eu sei o único jeito de ganhar foco para uma janela é dando um alert()

Answer (score 6):

A forma de se fazer isso é com a função `focus` do objeto `window` retornado pela abertura da janela.

Por exemplo:

```js
var janela = window.open('http://www.google.com.br');
setInterval(function() { 
    janela.focus();
}, 60000);
```

O problema é que isso parece não funcionar em vários navegadores, afinal eles querem evitar que scripts maliciosos fixem o foco do usuário numa determinada janela, tal como uma propaganda, por exemplo.

Testes realizados:

- Chrome: não funcionou (sem erros)
- Firefox: não funcionou (sem erros) e a popup abriu uma nova aba
- Internet Explorer: funcionou

Portanto, minha sugestão é evitar o uso de popup. Primeiro porque muitas vezes isso é uma tentativa de replicar funcionalidades de programas desktop em aplicações web. Segundo porque sempre vejo isso causando muitos efeitos colaterais e esbarrando em várias limitações, como o caso do Firefox, que abriu a popup numa nova aba.

Pense em uma solução alternativa, como as notificações aqui do StackOverflow ou do Facebook, por exemplo.

---

**Update**

Testei uma alternativa, reabrindo a popup no intervalo determinado:

```js
setInterval(function() { 
    window.open('http://www.google.com.br', 'minha_janela').focus();
}, 60000);
```

Entretanto, o resultado é o mesmo nos diversos navegadores, isto é, apenas o IE dá o foco de volta à popup. A diferença é que a página é atualizada a cada abertura e, se a popup tiver sido fechada, ela é reaberta.

Comment: *O IE, como sempre, liderando os navegadores.* Que tal dar uma de ThePirateBay? `onclick=function(){/* o código acima*/; onclick=null};` (dica: não faça isso)

Comment: Falando sério agora: que tal usar [a API de notificações](http://www.w3.org/TR/notifications/) e em navegadores antigos usar os popups?

Comment: @GustavoRodrigues Eu testei essa API como descrito [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/notification) e não consegui exibir notificações. Sempre pede a permissão novamente. Também teste como [nesta questão do SOEN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271156/chrome-desktop-notification-example) e o resultado foi o mesmo. Iria editar a questão com essa alternativa, mas por enquanto nada feito. Quem sabe se tiver tempo livre faço outros testes. Se quiser arriscar adicionar uma resposta com um exemplo funcional terá meu *upvote* garantido.

Comment: O código dessa questão é para webkit, estou testando ele aqui e está funcionando. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xD6Wk/)

Comment: @GustavoRodrigues No meu Chrome não funciona. Deve ser por causa do Windows XP. Por que estou usando XP? Nem pergunte...

Comment: Também acho que notificações são um caminho melhor. [Essa questão aqui mesmo no SOPT](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2101/notificacoes-de-desktop-no-chrome-com-javascript/2103) trata mais do assunto e pode ter alguns exemplos úteis.

Comment: @LuizVieira Realmente, mas é bom considerar que isso ñao funciona em browsers antigos e ambientes restritos (como o meu). Como mencionei, as notificações não aparecem no Windows XP aqui do meu trabalho.

Answer (score 2):

```
var p = window.open("about:blank", "_blank", "width=610,height=610");
p.location = "http://www.google.com.br";

setInterval(function(){
    p.focus();
}, 60000);
```

Faça a chamada de `var p` antes de qualquer outra coisa em sua rotina para evitar que caia no bloqueador de pop-up.

Comment: Na verdade geralmente ela só não cai no bloqueador se o `window.open` for chamado por decorrência direta de uma ação do usuário: um evento de clique, keydown ou outros.

Comment: @GustavoRodrigues exatamente, por isso eu prefiro sempre fazer dessa forma. Quis dar ênfase ao método `location` justamente por isso!