# PHP + Delphi(Pascal), emitir avisos em tempo real

Tags: php, delphi

Gostaria de elaborar um sistema, pequeno e simples, codificado na linguagem Pascal(IDE delphi), para receber notificações(como por exemplo, um aviso que algum evento ocorreu), ao receber o aviso tocar algum som.

Entendo pouco de Delphi, foi uma das linguagens que comecei apenas por curiosidade mas acabei largando depois que vim para plataforma WEB.

Não sei se é possível, criar algo com PHP + Delphi, algo como enviar um e-mail, o software capturar e emitir algum alerta(como um som) para o cliente.

Gostaria que fosse possível essa ligação de delphi com PHP, mas não sei se é possível interagir uma linguagem da plataforma web com outra que não é, de forma direta.

Comment: O seu software que roda no cliente e em PHP?

Comment: Fornece mais informações na pergunta, talvez aja uma solução, eu to tendo dificuldade em entender o que vc que.

Comment: Eu quero saber o caminho para criar um programa capaz de receber notificações de uma linguagem da plataforma WEB( como em PHP ) afim de notificar o cliente. Ou seja, é acionado um evento e direcionado para o meu programa que fica instalado no computador do cliente, e o programa alerta de alguma maneira o evento(como tocando um som). O evento este seria iniciado por uma linguagem server-side, no caso o PHP.

Comment: @DenerCarvalho Não teria como eu fazer tudo em PHP, já que para eu emitir algo para o navegador do cliente, ele precisa requisitar, então eu pensei em criar um programa que fica-se hospedado no computador dele(escrito em Pascal, IDE Delphi) afim de fazer a idéia funcionar, onde o gatilho(disparo do evento) fosse inicializado pelo PHP.

Comment: Da uma olhada nesta pergunta ve se é o que vc precisa http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2101/notifica%C3%A7%C3%B5es-de-desktop-no-chrome-com-javascript

Comment: Não queria que depende-se do navegador, até por questões de compatibilidade e de funcionalidade, e também pela questão que o cliente precisaria estar na página para ver a notificação. A ideia é ter um software instalado no computador do cliente, que recebe-se notificações enviadas pela tecnologia PHP, afim de processa-las como foi programado, logo o software consumiria internet e capturaria as requisições feitas a ele afim de processa-las e avisar ao cliente. Não precisa ser uma receita de bolo, mas um caminho, alguma noção de como posso dar o primeiro passo.

Comment: Vc pode escrever uma aplicação desktop que faz conexão com o banco de dados do seu sistema web, poderia ser uma solução na integração da aplicação desktop com o sistema web.

Comment: Vc pode criar um app em delphi simples, que fica ali no relógio e conectado ao banco de dados, quando houver a mudança no banco, dispara um callback pro software, ou ele vai ao banco sabe se houve mudanças, 15 em 15 mim. Sem conectar o app no banco, vc criar um app em delphi em REST, assim tu pode consumir os métodos via JS e php, por exemplo quando alguem no teu site envia uma pergunta tu chama o método no servidor rest em delphi e ele avisa lá na área de trabalho. Criar um serviço REST em delphi é muito facil.

Comment: @Artur_Indio Obrigado pela resposta! Abriu novos olhares, se você poder deixar algum link de referência, seria melhor ainda para mim me guiar, mas de antemão te agradeço pelas palavras.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sugiro a seguinte arquitetura:
- WebService PHP no servidor;
- Aplicação Desktop, Delphi, consultando o WS do servidor.

Para a aplicação desktop, não tem muito segredo, utilize o Timer, e faça a aplicação fica la no Tray do Windows, você pode utilizar este componente: [**QTrayIcon**](http://www.devmedia.com.br/utilizando-o-componente-ttrayicon-no-delphi/25088).

Para as chamadas ao servidor, você pode utilizar a biblioteca [**Indy**](http://www.indyproject.org/index.en.aspx).

No servidor, no PHP é simples para você fazer um WebService simples que lê a chamada via GET e retorna se foram feitas alterações ou não, você pode retornar com um JSON, contendo as respostas desejadas, algo assim:

```
.htaccess
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?pg=$1
```

Exemplo de WS simples:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

$dadosRecebidos = $_GET['pg']);

switch ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {
    case 'GET':
        if ($dadosRecebidos[0] == TESTE){
            echo json_encode(array(MSG_OK, "CONEXAO OK"));
    case ...
...
```

*Sugiro também migrar do Delphi para o [**Lazarus**](http://www.lazarus-ide.org/), tudo **open-source**!*

Comment: Eu gostaria de ter tempo para ler e aplicar isso antes de encerrar o período de recompensa,.. obrigado pela resposta Celso!

Comment: @AlexandreC.Caus, não se preocupe com a recompensa... espero ter ajudado! E qualquer dúvida posta aê!

Comment: @CelsoMarigoJr Fiquei curioso com esse Lazarus. É possível migrar código fonte de um para outro?

Comment: @MarcosRegis, é possível sim migrar de Delphi para Lazarusm inclusive existe dentro da própria IDE dele uma ferramenta para isso. Apesar de não ser perfeita a conversão, facilita um pouco.

Answer (score 5):

Outra maneira de implementar este recurso, que ninguém comentou, é através do uso de [Webhooks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webhook).

O uso de "polling", ou seja, ficar consultando o servidor de tempo em tempo (via consulta http ou mesmo através de acesso direto ao banco de dados) é ineficiente em alguns casos.

Se a estrutura que o amigo Alexandre apresentou permitir que a aplicação web se conecte ao terminal do cliente, é possível criar uma aplicação em Delphi que seja um mini servidor web que irá aguardar conexões. Quando esse servidor web receber alguma conexão, ele mesmo poderá exibir a mensagem de alguma forma para o usuário (na área de notificações, por exemplo).

A vantagem dos webhooks é que a notificação irá acontecer em tempo real, ou seja, no exato momento em que o evento ocorrer na aplicação web.

Um framework interessante, que pode facilitar a implementação deste recurso é o [Brook Framework](http://silvioprog.github.io/brookframework/).

Answer (score 4):

Atualmente eu uso isto em um sistema no interior onde eu morava, funciona basicamente como você pretende.

A aplicação web é responsável por receber pedidos ou encomendas feitas pelo cliente, e o aplicativo na Loja do proprietário fica 'escutando' o banco de dados online o tempo todo, quando o cliente efetua um pedido/encomenda/orçamento/duvida eu gravo em um campo especifico do banco.

Lógica usada no Web:

```
pedido = 1
encomenda = 2
orcamento = 3
duvida = 4
```

Na aplicação Desktop (eu usei um timer = o colega anterior mencionou, porem em um intervalo bem menor, a cada 30 segundos eu executo um Select no banco que é bem pequeno não gerando carga alguma no Banco que esta Online):

```
if (resultado sql do campo especificado) = 1 (ou qualquer outro listado acima) then
begin
  //Aqui eu solicito o Som (sim o som, gravei com uma moça de voz suave o aviso)
end;
```

O cliente que me requisitou um sistema desses hoje tem 2 Lojas e já esta abrindo uma terceira, e previamente já me pediu liberação para uso na terceira loja! O ramo de atividade dele é Construção civil mas poderia ser usado em qualquer ramo!

Comment: Valeu pela resposta Júnior, tentarei aplicar antes de dar a recompensa a melhor resposta.