# Notificação Push com Socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, push-notification, socket.io

Fiz uma pequena aplicação com node + socket.io para envio de notificação. 
adicionando o código abaixo na página do cliente, a notificação é exibida na div "messagebox".

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:4555/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io('http://localhost:4555', {transports: ['websocket', 'polling', 'flashsocket']});
  socket.on('notificacao', function (data) {
    document.getElementById('messagebox').innerHTML = data;

  });
</script>

<div id="messagebox">
```

Minha dúvida agora é como fazer para aparecer aquelas notificações no estilo do facebook. ou para ser mais claro igual as notificações do pushcrew.

Não encontrei nada que possa me ajudar :/ alguém tem algum material ou sabe como posso fazer isso ?

Comment: Eu não entendi o que você quer exatamente, poderia explicar melhor?

Comment: @RafaelAugusto Bom dia Rafael posso sim, seguinte... da forma que eu fiz, assim que disparo a notificação ela aparece na pagina pela div MESSAGEBOX porém eu gostaria de invés de aparecer na div, aparece-se dessa forma aquii --> prntscr.com/joj5xi eu não consegui fazer isso :/

Comment: O que você quer é utilizar a API do `HTML`, `Notification` da uma olhada https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API

Comment: @RafaelAugusto  já tinha visto essa documentação, mas não consegui integrar com a minha aplicação, por falta de conhecimento mais avançado sobre o assunto :/, mesmo assim obrigado.

Comment: Vou montar um exemplo funcional para você

Comment: @RafaelAugusto ta joia, obrigado cara :)

Comment: @RafaelAugusto pode verificar oq está errado nesse código --> http://prntscr.com/jokj9q quando envio a notificação aparece o alerta para aceitar, a notificação aparece no console, porém ela não é exibida como eu disse dessa forma -->  http://prntscr.com/joj5xi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acho que uma solução para o seu problema seria esse

```
var socket = io('http://localhost:4555', {transports: ['websocket', 'polling', 'flashsocket']});
socket.on('notificacao', function (data) {
    console.log(data) //VERIFIQUE OS DADOS QUE ESTÃO CHEGANDO 
    notify(data.nome,data.mensagem)
});

function notify(nome,mensagem) {
    Notification.requestPermission(function() {
        var notification = new Notification(nome, {
            icon: 'ICONE DA SUA APLICAÇÃO',
            body: mensagem
        });
        notification.onclick = function() {
            //SUA LÓGICA AQUI
        }
    });
}
```

Código baseado em: [Notificações de desktop no Chrome com Javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2101/notifica%C3%A7%C3%B5es-de-desktop-no-chrome-com-javascript)

Comment: Obrigado pela contribuição, mas eu não consegui juntar esse código com o meu para fazer funcionar :/

Comment: Aparece algum erro?

Comment: Eu editei a minha resposta, copie esse código e dê uma olhada no seu console

Comment: opa, apareceu assim no console --> http://prntscr.com/jokdyq mas a notificação não apareceu, e sempre que disparo ele pergunta se quero aceitar receber notificação

Comment: fiz isso --> http://prntscr.com/jokj9q mas a notificação ainda não aparece :/

Comment: Você deve permitir a notificação uma vez, para depois ela começar a aparecer. Isso é do próprio browser.

Comment: então, sempre que eu envio a notificação ele solicita que eu permita receber, eu clico em PERMITIR envio novamente e ele me torna e perguntar se quero receber :) mas não cria a notificação, só aparece no console

Comment: Descobrir o problema :) quando subi a aplicação para um servidor funcionou :) obrigado amigo.