# Nenhuma notificação aparece no chrome somente no firefox

Tags: javascript, html5, google-chrome

nao consigo fazer funcionar a notificação no chrome, apenas no mozila, alguem tem uma solução????

```js
        //Verifica e solicita se o usuario tem permissao para utilizar as notificações do Chrome
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            if (!Notification) {
                alert('Erro no sistema de notificação, navegador não suportado.');
                return;
            }

            if (Notification.permission !== "granted")
                Notification.requestPermission();
        });

        function minhaNotificao() {
            if (Notification.permission !== "granted") {
                Notification.requestPermission();
            }
            else {
                var notificacao = new Notification("Titulo da notificacao", {
                    icon: 'go.jpg', //img
                    body: 'Mensagem'
                });

                notificacao.onclick = function () {
                    window.open('http://google.com/'); //site
                };
            }
        }

        minhaNotificao();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Notificações</h1>
    <input type="button" value="Notificar!" onclick="minhaNotificao()">
   
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Duplicado:
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2101/notifica%C3%A7%C3%B5es-de-desktop-no-chrome-com-javascript

Comment: eu postei pq essa  publicação mencionada nao ta funcionando aqui pra mim!

Answer (score 1):

Falta um `else` acaso não esteja permitido o uso disto pelo usuário, aliais todo seu código esta sem sentido, tem um evento que executa após o `DOMContentLoaded` e outro que executa deliberadamente quando o script é carregado.

Para resumir tem que usar o `callback` no `Notification.requestPermission` para checar as permissões quando não garantido e se for diferente de `granted` você pode informar ao usuário que ele negou o acesso, ai só resetando as configurações no navegador para o site espeficio para que funcione.

```js
function notificar()
{        
    var notificacao = new Notification('Titulo da notificacao', {
        icon: 'go.jpg', //img
        body: 'Mensagem'
    });

    notificacao.onclick = function () {
        window.open('http://google.com/'); //site
    };
}

function semPermissao()
{
    console.warn('O usuário não permitiu notificações');
}

function minhaNotificao()
{
    if (!('Notification' in window)) {
        console.warn("Este browser não suporta notificações de Desktop");
    } else if (Notification.permission === 'granted') {
        notificar();
    } else if (Notification.permission !== 'denied') {
        Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) {
            if (permission === 'granted') {
                notificar();
            } else {
                semPermissao();
            }
        });
    } else {
        semPermissao();
    }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', minhaNotificao);
```

Note que no Gecko 46 (provavelmente Firefox 45) o uso do callback é obsoleto, deve-se usar *promises*, como por exemplo:

```
function notificar()
{        
    var notificacao = new Notification("Titulo da notificacao", {
        icon: 'go.jpg', //img
        body: 'Mensagem'
    });

    notificacao.onclick = function () {
        window.open('http://google.com/'); //site
    };
}

function semPermissao()
{
    console.warn("O usuário não permitiu notificações");
}

function minhaNotificao()
{
    if (!('Notification' in window)) {
        console.warn("Este browser não suporta notificações de Desktop");
    } else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
        notificar();
    } else if (Notification.permission !== 'denied') {
        Notification.requestPermission().then(function (permission) {
            if (permission === "granted") {
                notificar();
            } else {
                semPermissao();
            }
        });
    } else {
        semPermissao();
    }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', minhaNotificao);
```

---

### Habilitando notificações nos navegadores

Se no console do navegador CHROME aparecer a mensagem:

> O usuário não permitiu notificações

Então navegue pare este endereço

```
chrome://settings/content/notifications
```

Então clique no botão do site que estiver bloqueado e selecione "Allow" (se o seu navegador estiver em portugues selecione "Permitir"):

> [image: permitir notificações no chrome]

No Firefox navegue até `about:preferences#privacy` então procure por isto (ou algo semelhante):

> [image: configurações de privacidade do Firefox]

E depois no site que deseja permitir selecione Allow (ou Permitir):

> [image: permitir notificações no Firefox]

Comment: o erro que da é Uncaught ReferenceError: notificar is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.minhaNotificao

Comment: e como posso fazer carregar sem o usuario clicar, coloquei window.onload, seria isso?

Comment: @EvandroAguiar indica que a função esta sendo chamada em outro lugar, você com certeza colou em lugar ou de forma errada. Não precisa de window.onload, olha os códigos que postei, estão usando `DOMContentLoaded`, isso já resolve. Com certeza você esta com outro problema no seu código, refaça com calma e com certeza vai dar certo.

Comment: ta tudo certinho, fiz com a sua resposta, porem acho que o problema é no chrome mesmo, no mozilla roda show

Comment: @EvandroAguiar A mensagem de erro `Uncaught ReferenceError: notificar is not defined at HTMLDocument.minhaNotificao` indica que as funções estão em escopos diferentes e que provavelmente você fez algo bem diferente do informado na resposta, manda o link do seu site para ver o que fez.